# XSL Transformation with recursive elements

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, transformation

I have an XML with approximately the following structure, the relevant characteristic here the recursive relation of the element pair "F" and "Child_Fs". "Child_Fs" can contain any number of "F" and "F" can contain only one "Child_Fs":

```
<A>
    <B>
        <F id="1">
            <J/>
            <K/>
            <Child_Fs>
                <F id="1.1">
                    <J/>
                    <K/>
                    <Child_Fs>
                        <F id="1.1.1">
                            <J/>
                            <K/>
                            <Child_Fs>
                                    ...
                            </Child_Fs>
                        </F>
                        <F id="1.1.2">
                            ...
                        </F>
                        <F id="1.1.3">
                            ...
                        </F>
                        <F id="1.1.4">
                            ...
                        </F>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </Child_Fs>
                </F>
                <F id="1.2">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.3">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.4">
                    ...
                </F>
                .
                .
                .
            </Child_Fs>
        </F>
        <F id="2">
            ...
        </F>
        <F id="3">
            ...
        </F>
        <F id="4">
            ...
        </F>
        .
        .
        .
        <G/>
        <H/>
        <I/>
    </B>
    <C/>
    <D/>
    <E/>
</A>
```

My actual XML doesn't contains IDs, I just wrote them in this example for ilustration purposes.

So what I would like to get after the transformations is the following XML, in which all "F" elements are children of their corresponding highest "F/Child_Fs" ancestor. Meaning that the maximal depth for an F element should be of only two occurrances (F/Child_Fs/F/Childfs). The other important requirement here is to keep all data (attributes and text inclusive) intact, it is just a relocation operation:

```
<A>
    <B>
        <F id="1">
            <J/>
            <K/>
            <Child_Fs>
                <F id="1.1">
                    <J/>
                    <K/>
                    <Child_Fs>
                    </Child_Fs>
                </F>
                <F id="1.1.1">
                    <J/>
                    <K/>
                    <Child_Fs>
                    </Child_Fs>
                </F>
                ...
                <F id="1.1.2">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.1.3">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.1.4">
                    ...
                </F>
                .
                .
                .
                <F id="1.2">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.3">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.4">
                    ...
                </F>
                .
                .
                .
            </Child_Fs>
        </F>
        <F id="2">
            ...
        </F>
        <F id="3">
            ...
        </F>
        <F id="4">
            ...
        </F>
        .
        .
        .
        <G/>
        <H/>
        <I/>
    </B>
    <C/>
    <D/>
    <E/>
</A>
```

I would appreciate it a lot if anyone could give me a hint on this. Till now I've not been able to come up with a correct XSL Stylesheet.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is self - contradicting -- you say: "what I would like to get after the transformations is the following XML, in which all "F" elements are children of their corresponding highest "F" ancestor. " But, in the provided "wanted result `<F id="1.1"> ` is child of a `<Child_Fs>`. Please, edit the question and correct the contradictions.

Comment: Hello Dimitre, many thanks for your answer. It isn't yet what I am looking for but it is a good approximation. I will describe my requirement better, the problem is I cannot do it right now. I will update the requirement as soon as possible. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Child_Fs[ancestor::Child_Fs]">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<A>
    <B>
        <F id="1">
            <J/>
            <K/>
            <Child_Fs>
                <F id="1.1">
                    <J/>
                    <K/>
                    <Child_Fs>
                        <F id="1.1.1">
                            <J/>
                            <K/>
                            <Child_Fs>
                                    ...
                            </Child_Fs>
                        </F>
                        <F id="1.1.2">
                            ...
                        </F>
                        <F id="1.1.3">
                            ...
                        </F>
                        <F id="1.1.4">
                            ...
                        </F>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </Child_Fs>
                </F>
                <F id="1.2">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.3">
                    ...
                </F>
                <F id="1.4">
                    ...
                </F>
                .
                .
                .
            </Child_Fs>
        </F>
        <F id="2">
            ...
        </F>
        <F id="3">
            ...
        </F>
        <F id="4">
            ...
        </F>
        .
        .
        .
        <G/>
        <H/>
        <I/>
    </B>
    <C/>
    <D/>
    <E/>
</A>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<A>
   <B>
      <F id="1">
         <J/>
         <K/>
         <Child_Fs>
            <F id="1.1">
               <J/>
               <K/>
               <F id="1.1.1">
                  <J/>
                  <K/>
                                        ...
                                </F>
               <F id="1.1.2">
                                ...
                            </F>
               <F id="1.1.3">
                                ...
                            </F>
               <F id="1.1.4">
                                ...
                            </F>
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        </F>
            <F id="1.2">
                        ...
                    </F>
            <F id="1.3">
                        ...
                    </F>
            <F id="1.4">
                        ...
                    </F>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                </Child_Fs>
      </F>
      <F id="2">
                ...
            </F>
      <F id="3">
                ...
            </F>
      <F id="4">
                ...
            </F>
            .
            .
            .
            <G/>
      <H/>
      <I/>
   </B>
   <C/>
   <D/>
   <E/>
</A>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.

Comment: The OP has Child_Fs nodes in the expected result.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: The OP says: "what I would like to get after the transformations is the following XML, in which all "F" elements are children of their corresponding highest "F" ancestor". If he is contradicting himself, this is his problem. I have pointed out this issue in a comment.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: I guessed what the OP wants and posted a short solution. Thank you for alerting me.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the structure you describes holds in place, you can use a fairly simple algorithm as described below. If the structure becomes more free-form then it becomes a harder problem.

### Algorithm

Child_Fs with exactly 1 ancestor F:

- These are recipients. They will pull in all descendant F

Child_Fs with more than 1 ancestor F:

- These are donors. Copy other children but exclude F children

d

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
      exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xi">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
 
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Child_Fs[count(ancestor::F)=1]">
 <!-- Child_F which is recipient of all Fs. -->
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | //F" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="Child_Fs[count(ancestor::F) &gt; 1]">
 <!-- Child_F which is donor of Fs. -->
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::F)]" />
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello Sean, many thanks for your answer. It isn't yet what I am looking for but it is a good approximation. I will describe my requirement better, the problem is I cannot do it right now. I will update the requirement as soon as possible. Many thanks again.